# Use JQuery to scroll ListBox (select box) to certain item

Tags: .net, jquery

I have a list box control that contains enough items to list them with a scroll bar.

I'd like the user to be able to enter a few letters and have the ASP ListBox scroll to the first option whose text starts with those letters.

I'm hoping that JQuery offers some simple functionality or plug-in that works with the  element, but so far, I've only seen plug-ins that work with scrolling DIVs.

Is there a way to scroll an ASP ListBox to a specified option?

**EDIT**

As @Alex Sexton stated, you can just select the option via javascript and it will scroll there automatically.  Here is some simple JQuery to do just that:

```
$('#ListBox option:eq(6)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: write your answer as an answer below rather than editing the question to include answer.. or edit the existing answer to include your code snippet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser should handle the scroll automatically upon setting the selected attribute to "selected" on the element that you wish to put into view.